# manually updating database table values are not reflecting in webpage - aspnet mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i noticed some wierd problem i.e i have built a web page on which information comes from database table named "school", when i change some data in that table manually from mssql the web page data is still same as previous, its not gettin' changed, i dn't know how it is possible.

this is my action controller

```
    public ActionResult SchoolDetails(string id,_ASI_School schoolDetails)
    {
            schoolDetails = SchoolRepository.GetSchoolById(id);
            return View(schoolDetails);
     }
```

This is my view

```
    =Html.Encode(Model.SchoolName)
    = Html.Encode(Model.SchoolAddress) 
    = Html.Encode(Model.SchoolEmail)
```

code for GetSchoolById()..

```
   private static ASIDataContext db = new ASIDataContext();
   public static _ASI_School GetSchoolById(string schoolId)
   {
            return db._ASI_Schools.SingleOrDefault(x => x.SchoolId == schoolId);
   }
```

Comment: Did you refresh the web page in your web browser after changing the database?

Comment: yes ofcourse i did that, but no use

Comment: @FosterZ, Probably due to a cache.

Comment: @Mattias Jakobsson, i cleared all cache of browser, even i tried to open in various browser, but same issue.

Comment: It does not seem to be a complicated scenario, so debugging it should not be too difficult for you. If you still require help, you might want to post some source code (view, controller, underlying layers)

Comment: i have edit with code snippet and yes your right, its not a complicated scenario, i hv checked deleting the total row from the table and its get reflected but when i change a single field like "schooName" then its not getting reflected.. m not gettin' from where the page getting the old values..

Comment: `SchoolRepository.GetSchoolById(id)` - there's the problem, unfortunately cannot say where as you didn't provide the source code for this method.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, i have edited my snippet, what could be the problem ?

Comment: Do you have a `[OutputCache]` attribute on your Action method `public ActionResult SchoolDetails(string id,_ASI_School schoolDetails)`?

Answer (score 1):

try putting this above your SchoolDetails ActionResult

```
[OutputCache( Duration=0)]
```

MVC does some really nice server side caching as well that clearing the cache on the browser does not fix.